# How do I write long sustaining notes in Guitar Pro 7.5

Tags: guitar-pro

When I'm writing a long sustaining guitar note in Guitar Pro 7.5, its volume decays after about 3 bars (this is in RSA mode). This seems to mimic the natural note decay that happens in real guitars, but in my case I need the note to sustain at full volume for as long as I need it to (spanning as many bars as I need). How can I disable the volume decay in the playback?

Comment: You could try adding a heavy compressor to the track, but I'm not sure what else you could do without replacing that note with some sort of synth track; Guitar Pro tries its best to simulate what a real guitar would do.